# if-else in HAML (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to use if-else to render some default image (being a user's avatar) if the 'user' doesn't have an avatar. (This is to avoid the depressing missing.png image). But it's not working so far.

Here is my view (view.html.haml file):

```
...
.user_avatar
 -img_path = defined?(@user.avatar.url) ? "@{user.avatar.default_url}" : "@user.avatar.url"
 %img{:src => img_path}
...
```

Here is my model:

```
...
attr_accessible :name, :avatar

has_attached_file :avatar :default_url => "assets/images/default_icon.png"
...
```

Note that if I used `@user.avatar.icon.url` in the `img` tag, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is:

```
.user_avatar
 -img_path = defined?(@user.avatar.url) ? @user.avatar.url : @user.avatar.default_url
 %img{:src => img_path}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are just generating a string, not evaluating the code. When you do:

```
"@{user.avatar.default_url}"
```

You are getting just exactly that string. What you probably meant to do was:

```
@user.avatar.default_url
```

Not as a string. This way it actually gets evaluated. The same thing goes for `"@user.avatar.url"`.

**EDIT**

Change:

```
-img_path = defined?(@user.avatar.url) ? @user.avatar.default_url : @user.avatar.url
```

To:

```
-img_path = defined?(@user.avatar.url) ? @user.avatar.url : @user.avatar.default_url
```

In other words, if the user has a defined avatar URL, then use it, *else* use the default URL.

Also, consider throwing this in to a method on user, like `User#avatar_url`, which can do this `if/else` logic itself.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's still not working. (I still see the 'missing.png' image instead of my default icon)

Comment: I think you also have it backwards.

Comment: I changed it to what you said, but the image is still the `/icons/original/missing.png` icon

Comment: Is there any way to do that in my model? (What decides the icon to bhe the `missing.icon` when there is no link (or broken link) to the real icon?)

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, please check that the url to you default image is correct, if the image is in the `app/assets/images` folder, `default_icon.png` should suffice as a url.

Secondly, instead of manually writing the `%img`tag, consider using a helper:

```
= image_tag @user.avatar.url
```

Thirdly, although I can't test it right now I'm pretty sure that the point of defining a `default_url` in paperclip is to be able to just call `@user.avatar.url` and having it return the default url automagically if there is not avatar.

In other words: doing it like your proposal kinda defeats the purpose.

My five cents is that the image url you've provided is wrong and that once you have the correct url, my code above will suffice.